# c# string initiates to "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"

Tags: c#, .net

So I am trying to experiment with hashtables saved on disk. When I try to debug and debugger gets to **POINT 1**, I open variables and see that `Data` and `Key` value gets an exception `'this.Key' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'`. I step over to **POINT 2**, and now `Data` gets value of `"00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"`. **So from where that weird value is comming from?** I have also put breakpoints on `Data` get and set, but by the time these points were not hit.

```
class HashtableFile
    {
        class Hashentry
        {
            const int KEY_BYTES = 4;
            const int DATA_BYTES = 12;
            public int? Key
            {
                get
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[KEY_BYTES];
                    fs.Seek((KEY_BYTES + DATA_BYTES) * Index, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    fs.Read(bytes, 0, KEY_BYTES);
                    int data = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
                    return data;
                }
                set
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[KEY_BYTES];
                    int key = value.GetValueOrDefault(0);
                    bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(key);
                    fs.Seek(KEY_BYTES * Index, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, KEY_BYTES);
                }
            }
            public string Data
            { 
                get
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[DATA_BYTES];
                    //seek key too
                    fs.Seek(((KEY_BYTES + DATA_BYTES) * Index) + KEY_BYTES, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    fs.Read(bytes, 0, DATA_BYTES);
                    string data = BitConverter.ToString(bytes, 0);
                    return data;
                }
                set
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[DATA_BYTES];
                    string data = value ?? string.Empty;
                    data = data.Insert(data.Length, new string(' ', DATA_BYTES - data.Length));
                    bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                    fs.Seek(((KEY_BYTES + DATA_BYTES) * Index) + KEY_BYTES, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, DATA_BYTES);
                }
            }
            private int Index;
            private FileStream fs;
            public Hashentry(int? key, string data, int index, FileStream fs)//POINT 1
            {
                this.fs = fs;
                Index = index; // POINT 2
                Key = key;
                Data = data;
            }
            public int GetIndex()
            {
                return Index;
            }
            public int? GetKey()
            {
                return Key;
            }
            public string GetData()
            {
                return Data;
            }
        }

        private int maxSize;
        private Hashentry[] table;
        private string file;
        private FileStream fs;
        public HashtableFile(int size, string filename)
        {
            file = filename;
            if (File.Exists(file))
                File.Delete(file);
            fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            maxSize = size;
            table = new Hashentry[maxSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
            {
                table[i] = new Hashentry(null, null, i, fs);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at

```
public int? Key
{
    get
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[KEY_BYTES];
        fs.Seek((KEY_BYTES + DATA_BYTES) * Index, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

You see? The second line of the `Key` getter is using `fs`. If `fs == null` (default uninitialized value for a field of a class) then `NullReferenceException` if you try to use `Key`

BUT

```
public Hashentry(int? key, string data, int index, FileStream fs)//POINT 1
{
    this.fs = fs;
    Index = index; // POINT 2
```

the first line of the constructor sets the `fs`! So no more `NullReferenceException`. So at `POINT 1`, `this.fs == null`, while at `POINT 2`, `this.fs = something`

Comment: So getters are called before class constructor?

Comment: @Mazas You wrote: *I open variables and see that Data and Key value gets an exception 'this.Key'*... It isn't that "getters are called by a divine being before class constructor", it is "I'm calling getters before class construtor by looking at them with debug"

Comment: Okay, but still, how does that value of "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00" shows up?

Comment: @Mazas *fs* is a *FileStream*, so an object used to read/write files... You should look the caller what *FileStream* is passing and see what data is present in the file.

Comment: this occurs even on first loop call. So by the time file is empty. Also the amount of "00" is equal to `DATA_BYTES`.

Comment: @Mazas because *BitConverter.ToString(bytes, 0);* formats the array in that way, and *bytes = new byte[DATA_BYTES];*

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that

```
string data = BitConverter.ToString(bytes, 0);
```

converts bytes directly to to string, not to ***corresponding*** characters. Solution was to change this line to:

```
string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```